# PHP Last item in array is empty within foreach

Tags: php, arrays, database, foreach

I have an issue where the last item in an array ($item) is coming across empty for some reason when I insert results into a DB.

```
$foo = 0;
$bar = 0;
$item = array(); // the problem array

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
     $query = "SELECT data FROM table0 WHERE column = '$value'";
     $result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query) or trigger_error();

     $data = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_NUM);

     if ($data[0] =='1'){
          $foo = $foo + 1;
          $bar = $bar + $data[1];
     }else{
          $item[] = $data[2];
     }
}

foreach ($item as $number){
     $query2 = "SELECT data FROM table1 WHERE column = '$number'";
     $result2 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query2) or trigger_error();

     $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result2, MYSQL_NUM);

     $query3 = "INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('', '$row[0]', '$row[1]')";
     $result3 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query3) or trigger_error();
}
```

The last row that gets inserted from $query3 has no values because the $item array has an empty value at the end of it.

$item ends up looking something like `array ([0]=>1 [1]=>2 [2]=>3 [3]=>)` but there is nothing empty in the $_POST array.

Thank you for any feedback in advanced.

Comment: You probably have a value in `$_POST` that doesn't have a matching value in the table. You should check that `$data` is not empty.

Comment: `if ($data) { // code to add to $item }`

Comment: @Barmar: I checked the $_POST array and there are no empty values.

Comment: You need to inspect your `$_POST` variable..  You have a value that doesn't match your table.  It's most likely your submit button, ie, `<input type="submit" value="submit"/>`.  The submit input is included in a post request too, ya know..

Comment: You're only selecting one column from the table. There will never be anything in `$data[1]` or `$data[2]`. I don't understand how this is working at all, unless you didn't post the actual query.

Comment: you should use a prepared statement to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: You are wide open for [SQL Injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Comment: @Shannon I never said anthing about empty POST values, I said `$data` will be empty when the `SELECT` query doesn't find anything.

Comment: Yes, in my actual code I have an if statement that says if $key != 'submit' then run the rest.  But I will look at it again to see if there is something else triggering it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to check that the `SELECT` query found something.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
     $query = "SELECT data FROM table0 WHERE column = '$value'";
     $result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query) or trigger_error();

     $data = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_NUM);
     if ($data) {
         if ($data[0] =='1'){
              $foo = $foo + 1;
              $bar = $bar + $data[1];
         }else{
              $item[] = $data[2];
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, as with most errors it had to do with spelling and it was in the $_POST array.